# Python get unique element in array but maintain its original sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to get the unique element from an array with specific sequences.

For example,

initially, I have array as following:

```
array([3, 3, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 8, 8])
```

I would like to get the unique element from the array above and maintain its original order sequence. The **sample output** as following:

```
array([3, 6, 5, 2, 8])
```

I know that using `numpy.unique()` will get the unique elements for the array, but it will return sorted unique elements. However, in my case, I need the output in the original sequence.

To generate toy example, here easy for you to just copy & paste

```
arr = np.array([3,3,6,6,5,5,5,5,2,8,8])
```

At the time I post this, I still working on this, and I wish to get your suggestion so that I could move to the next part of work. Your advice will be highly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Just loop over the array elements, collecting the unique elements into a list, then convert the list back into an array.

Comment: What would be the result for `[3, 6, 6, 3]` or can't this happen?

Comment: I assume it would be [3, 6]

Comment: @Barmar I'm having a hard time imagining how to *collecting the unique elements into a list*. A dict/set, yes. A list alone, not quite clear how. That said, this sounds like just `np.unique(arr)`.

Comment: Loop through the array elements. If the array element is already in the result list, skip it, otherwise append it to the result.

Comment: You could also use a list comprehension, although a for loop would be faster :
`[x for i, x in enumerate(arr) if arr.index(x) == i]`

Comment: @Barmar that's a `O(n^2)` approach when there are no duplicates, while `dict/set` approach is most likely `O(n)` or `O(n logn)`. Still surprise no suggestion for `np.unique`.

Comment: something like this @QuangHoang?

import numpy as np
arr = np.array([3,3,6,6,5,5,5,5,2,8,8])
_, idx = np.unique(arr, return_index=True)
print(arr[np.sort(idx)])

Comment: @balandongiv yes indeed! Forgot that unique sorts the values.

Comment: IIUIC, OP request `preserved order` @QuangHoang, hence the above suggestion

Comment: Thank you everyone! I truly appreciate your valuable advice and comment. It is really awesome and I enjoy to discuss here. For this question, I received private feedback stated that this question has been asked in another post, but I found that the post given is actually refer to list, not array. Thus, I will keep this post. Thank you again!

Comment: @QuangHoang I was just trying to point him in the right direction, not provide the best solution. I'm trying not to write the code for him.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar I appreciate your guidance! =)

Answer (score 2):

Try this snippet:

```
arr = np.array([3,3,6,6,5,5,5,5,2,8,8])
unique = []
[unique.append(n) for n in arr if n not in unique]
print(np.array(unique))
```

Comment: Hi Keziya, thank you for your answer! I have tried the snippet, but I get the result as this `[None, None, None, None, None]`. Then I rearrange the line to make it a nested loop and got the correct result.